# How can i remove all UIViews from rootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently at `topViewController` while a `UIView` is added to my `rootViewController`. Is there any way that I can remove all `UIViews` before going to `rootViewController` via `popToRootViewContoller`?

Comment: can you explain what you actually mean by "topViewConrtoller"?

Comment: did you add new views as subviews?

Comment: do this in viewWillDisapper because whenever you again come to your rootView all the view in initialized againg..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];


    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {

        [subview removeFromSuperview];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Going back action,type following code:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And then type `popToRootViewContoller`.

Answer (score 1):

In `viewWillDisappear` you can do this task, when you are leaving your `rootViewController` then this method will call , so you can remove your view at this point.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in `viewWillAppear:` method of YourViewController

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: `self.view.subviews` is changing during iteration. This may cause assertions on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourView removeFromSuperView]
```

but added `subviews` willnot be there when you pop a `UIViewController`, so i don't think you need to do this

Comment: Why would you edit grammatical errors back into your post after I've fixed them?

Comment: @0x7fffffff this is not  place to correct grammar! better post the answer if you can

Comment: Yes it is. Maybe you should read about editing privileges: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit

Comment: yeah, i know that, if you didn't notice try to find the following line in it too:: "Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged."